# Can an "unregistered" user accept an answer to their question?

Tags: discussion, user-accounts

I notice many questions (and answers) posted by accounts which are subsequently marked as "unregistered".

I am guessing that a user will setup an account, post a question, and then "delete" the account; and that this will mark the account as unregistered.  This appears to routinely happen immediately after the question has been posted.

Is an unregistered account user able to vote on and accept an answer for the question they have posed, or do such question forever remain with no accepted answer?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

One of the *features* of Stack Exchange is that you [don't have to register](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/70481/232449) to participate in the site.  You can ask questions, post answers, and even [gain rep](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/81409/232449) as an unregistered user, and yes, [you can accept answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/37235/232449) to your questions while unregistered.

Unregistered users are tracked by cookie.  So when someone new comes to the site and has not registered, if they come back to the site on the same computer with the same cookie, they are recognized as the same unregistered user.  If that person switches computers or deletes their cookies, that user is essentially lost unless they go through the process of [merging their accounts](https://money.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts).

I would say that it is rare that an unregistered user comes back and accepts an answer.  However, it is [not really necessary](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/119198/232449) that all our questions are marked as accepted.  Once an answer has a score of at least "1," the question is marked in the system as "answered," and it won't show up in the [unanswered questions list](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions?sort=unanswered) anymore.

Comment: Thanks.  That's cleared that up.  I had believed otherwise.  I assume that it is the act of posting that creates the account with an unregistered status.

Comment: @NickR It is. A user account needs to be associated with every post, but the user account doesn't need to be a registered user account. This has implications also when users are destroyed for various reasons. (Source: I've been a diamond moderator on two sites in the network, and have participated in destroying user accounts on both.)